# Cookies returning undefined

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm building a small HTML game that uses cookies/localStorage to save and load users data. I have an object declared that holds all of the data which is then referenced by the save/load functions and by game calculations:

```
var iAttack, iDefence, iGold;
// nothing to do with Apple lol...

var data = {
    pStats: {
        attack: iAttack,
        defence: iDefence
    },
    pInventory: {
        gold: iGold
    }
}
```

These will obviously return `undefined`, but this is before the cookie values are inserted.
So, heres a run-through of whats supposed to happen:

When the window loads, the if statements are gone through to check cookies/localStorage and if there is any previous storage data in the browser. These booleans get assigned to `cookies`, `storageLocal` and `previousData`. This is the code for it:

```
var previousData = false;
var cookies = false;
var storageLocal = false;

//activated on window.load
function loadData(){



//check for previous data
    if (document.cookie != "") {
        previousData = true;
        console.log("Previous data? " + previousData)
    } else if (localStorage.getItem("gold") !== null) {
        previousData = true;
        console.log("Previous data? " + previousData)
    } else {
        console.log("Previous data? " + previousData)
    }


    // check if cookies/localStorage
    document.cookie = "foo=bar";
    if(document.cookie){
        cookies = true;
        console.log("Cookies will be used")
    } else if (typeof(localStorage) != undefined){
        storageLocal = true;
        console.log("localStorage will be used")
    }

    // loadData() continued...
```

If `previousData = false` then default values are assigned to the object variables, eg `iDefence = 5` and this works fine.

Lets assume that `previousData` and `cookies` are `true`: the function then goes on to inserting the data from the cookies into the object variables like this:

```
if (previousData) {    
        if (cookies){
            data.pStats.attack = parseInt( readCookie("attack") );
            data.pStats.defence = parseInt( readCookie("defence") );
            // note that i've used iAttack instead of data.pStats.attack but doesn't work
```

In the console, if i input `iAttack` or `data.pStats.attack` it returns `undefined`. This is the problem that been keeping me up all of last night trying to work around. Any help would be really appreciated.

---

---

---

This is the saveData function that is triggered by onclick. It inputs the object values into cookies:

```
function saveData(){
    if(cookies){
        createCookie("attack", iAttack, 7);
        createCookie("defence", iDefence, 7);
        //if its the first time saving then the default values of iAttack/def will be used
```

If you're curious about `createCookie()` and `readCookie()`, these are the functions:

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name,"",-1);
}
```